# Does Flask consume request body on redirects?

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

Sometimes, when Flask returns `308`, nginx returns `502`.

I changed unrelated details but here is how nginx logs look like

```
2023/11/02 12:25:26 [warn] 50#50: *43219 a client request body is buffered to a
temporary file /var/cache/nginx/client_temp/0000000014, client: xx.xx.xx.xx,
server: , request: "POST
/api/jobs?some_key=some_val
HTTP/1.1", host: "myhost"

2023/11/02 12:25:26 [error] 50#50: *43219 sendfile() failed (32: Broken pipe)
while sending request to upstream, client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: , request: "POST
    /api/jobs?some_key=some_val
    HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://127.0.0.1:5000", host: "myhost"

2023/11/02 12:25:26 [warn] 50#50: *43219 upstream server temporarily disabled
while sending request to upstream, client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: , request: "POST
    /api/jobs?some_key=some_val
    HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://127.0.0.1:5000", host: "myhost"
```

Temporary file buffering is totally ok as it is a bit larger(~2mb) request but I put
it also here in case it is interesting. Then, what comes next `sendfile` failing is
not what I'm expecting. Meanwhile, here is the related log from the uwsgi:

```
[pid: 10] xx.xx.xx.xx (-) [02/Nov/2023:12:25:26.000 +0000] uwsgi INFO {50 vars in 1739 bytes} [Thu Nov  2 12:25:26 2023] POST /api/jobs?some_key=some_val => generated 737 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 308) 3 headers in 355 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

It returns a `308` which is understandable because the correct url should be `/api/jobs/?` not `/api/jobs?`.

So sometimes when 308 is returned nginx gives 502 because it tries to send the request body.

We are serving a Flask app using uWSGI that is behind nginx proxy. we use nginx `ngx_http_uwsgi_module` and our `uwsgi.ini` looks like follwoing

```
[uwsgi]
protocol = uwsgi
callable = app
master = true
processes = 4
mount = ${UWSGI_MOUNT_LOCATION}=run.py
socket = 0.0.0.0:5000
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
enable-threads = true
wsgi-disable-file-wrapper = true
single-interpreter = true
need-app = true
```

Quoting the uwsgi documentation

> If an HTTP request has a body (like a POST request generated by a form), you have to read (consume) it in your application. If you do not do this, the communication socket with your webserver may be clobbered. If you are lazy you can use the post-buffering option that will automatically read data for you. For Rack applications this is automatically enabled.

I tried to understand why this happens and my best guess was Flask not reading the data when a redirection occurred.

However, I'm not quite sure.

I tried sending a multi-part body request to Flask where the URL was incorrect, it redirected to the correct URL however nginx reported failure stating that the sendfile was not successful.

I'm not sure as to if Flask always reads the body, or even if we are required to read the body etc.

Here is a minimum example, save it as `run.py`

```py
import os
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, url_for
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import logging

UPLOAD_FOLDER = './upload'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "Your_secret_string"

@app.route('/stg/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            app.logger.warning('no file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        # If the user does not select a file, the browser submits an
        # empty file without a filename.
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            app.logger.warning('empty filename')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file:
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return redirect(request.url)
    return '''
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Upload new File</title>
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <input type=file name=file>
      <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    '''
```

Run it with `uwsgi --http 127.0.0.1:5555 --master -p 4 -w run:app`

Then, go to cURL, `curl -X POST -F "file=@puthereanyfile.zip" http://localhost:5555/stg`

It will first redirect to `http://localhost:5555/stg/` and if you look at the uwsgi logs:

```
[pid: 210415|app: 0|req: 1/2] 127.0.0.1 () {46 vars in 2232 bytes} [Fri Nov  3 12:03:37 2023] GET /stg/ => generated 225 bytes in 5 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 2 headers in 80 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[uwsgi-http key: localhost:5555 client_addr: 127.0.0.1 client_port: 11401] hr_instance_read(): Connection reset by peer [plugins/http/http.c line 647]
```

In our development, we do not use uwsgi as HTTP server but it seems behavior is not dependent on that. If you fix the URL, then this connection reset by peer is gone. My assumption is because Flask does not read the input.

I tried this example also using uwsgi protocol in uWSGI and serving via nginx then nginx gives the following error

```
2023/11/03 14:51:42 [error] 386914#386914: *9 readv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "POST /stg HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://127.0.0.1:5555", host: "localhost"
```

But again if I fix the URL, no readv issue. Also, if I increase the file size I get a broken pipe instead of a readv. More I see it, more I think it is a bug.

--EDIT--

Well, I guess it is more of an expected behavior, you can see the discussion in the [Github](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/5319).

Comment: Post a [mre] including the configuration of nginx and source of the flask app. For example, are you using the [```Request.stream```](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#flask.Request.stream)? Then, it's your responsibility to read all data sent by the client.

Comment: @relent95 I've edited the question and provided a minimal reproducible example, please tell me if I missed any details

Comment: You called the ```request.files```. When it returned, the Flask already read all data sent by the client. So, the problem was caused by the uWSGI. What's your uWSGI version? I tested with 2.0.23 and it works fine. I suspect you are using an ancient version of uWSGI.

Comment: I rechecked the scenario. Because the flask is redirecting the request due to the routing mismatch, it doesn't matter whether you called the ```request.files``` or not. But the conclusion is the same. The uWSGI should handle the connection properly.

Comment: On server it is 2.0.22 and locally I tested with 2.0.21. After your remark, now I tested with 2.0.23 but the result is still the same. You might get your response to your request but in nginx you still get the readv or broken pipe error